# Azure Active Directory login redirect loop

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-identity, owin, azure-active-directory

I need to allow users to login through Corp network to access an internal web application.

I've followed all the steps given in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-aspnetwebapp) and it works fine.

However, a strange error that I am getting while logging in is that the authentication pages goes into a redirect loop every other day.

As per now the immediate fix for me is to change the `Application/Client ID` for the application in my `web.config` file.

```
<add key="ClientId" value="Enter_the_Application_Id_here" />
<add key="redirectUri" value="Enter_the_Redirect_URL_here" />
<add key="Tenant" value="common" />
<add key="Authority" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/v2.0" />
```

So as of now, I've got 2 different Applications created in [Microsoft Identity Platform](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/portal/) and I reuse the same `App Id` (switching them every time one stops working) and as soon as I change the `App Id`, the login starts working.

Not sure if I am missing something, but haven't found anything related to this exact problem other than a few like https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/219 which does not work for me. And to my understanding and suggestions over the internet if this was a Permission related issue, it should never allow login but it does.

Comment: This one might help you: https://github.com/Sustainsys/owin-cookie-saver.

Comment: @juunas, the current version of `Kentor.OwinCookieSaver` is not compatible with my current application framework i.e. `.Net version 4.5`.

Comment: :/ Maybe you can try implementing it based on the source code? :)

Comment: Have you been able to establish whether the redirect is being served by your own site, or by the azure AD login page?

Comment: @TomW, the current application has no login page. As soon as a user visits the root url, he's redirected to the Corporate Login Page, where he can get his credentials checked and if the login is successful it gets redirected to the application.

Comment: Is it possible you have a swithced up the redirecturls? so the processing of the login for App 1 is being handled on the App 2, which fails, tries to login for App 2, Azure redirects back to App 1, which fails,....

Comment: @Kiwi, `1`. The redirect loop is occurring on the Corp Login page, for which I have no control, which also means that, I can't check if login workflow broke somewhere in between. `2`. I tried using both the App ID's simultaneously (switching between them randomly), which I know makes no sense but I tried that and that too did not work.

Comment: Have you tried setting the appids to their correct values (unique per app) then clearing your cookies and trying to auth then? Possibly you've got some invalid state persisted somewhere.

Comment: @Mardoxx, yes I've already confirmed the `App ID`, and it is correct. Regarding clearing cookie, while searching for a possible fix, I've come to know that this is something related to cookie overwriting. Deleting the cookie from the browser console, forces it to validate the login again... but as this error has no specific pattern (like people mentioned that it is related to http and https), I cannot not identify if clearing the cookie will work or not.

Comment: 1) Are you using HTTPS everywhere? 2) Are you using roles? (`Authorize["Administrator"]`) ? 3) In your reply URL, are you using the entire URL? `https://myapp.domain.com/Home/Index`

Comment: @S.Walker, 1) Yes I am using HTTPS everywhere. 2) Yes I am using roles too (but had to remove the integrated `rolemanager` and have now written my own `rolemanager` due to some conflicts). 3) No, the return URL is just the `Root` url (excludes the `Controller/View` name).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that it was an issue with configuration of the AD.

I went to my `Azure App Service > Settings > Authentication/Authorization` and created a new AD App, and used the `App ID` of this `app` in my web application and it is now working fine.

Comment: If you are using multiple servers then I would recommend to have same machine key, otherwise you may experience unexpected logouts.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds strange that your corp login is in a loop. is it possible that it goes to your app but so 'fast' you don't notice it. I'm saying this because I have a web app and had a similar loop. and I found that the process was:

1. your app wants to login,
2. go to the corp login and do the login process,
3. To the app with the token,
4. Again to the corp login (still not fully sure why)
5. Back to the app with the token and then you are logged in

But if you check your login to soon. At step 3 it won't know it is logged in yet, so it goes back to step 1. hence the loop.

If your login sequence is auto triggered on app startup it could be the same as what I got.

Greetings Glenn

Comment: Exactly facing the same scenario, where after azure authentication navigate to login page of my application then automatically login to my application and navigate to dashboard page. Solve this issue using https://github.com/Sustainsys/owin-cookie-saver